# Heaven becomes boring?

Tags: jannah

I have not found the answer to this and I was wondering if Paradise is all pleasure and no goals, work, et cetera, wouldn't the soul's purpose be abolished and thus making them feel worthless and being bored with the idea of a utopia?

Comment: The question is, will boredom still be a part of our emotional or psychological state?

Comment: Your Lord is Exalted in Might , The Wise : His Power isnt limited so you are never going to get "tired" of being in Paradise. He will bless the believers with wonderful provision in sha Allah

Comment: @Abcd I would imagine, but is this mentioned in the Quran?

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin That is an interesting outlook, but surely with no desire or objective leaves you with nothing to continue with?

Comment: Yet it comes back to a similar question with mine above: Do we even have desire or objectives? They are all part of or related to our emotional state right? We might be brought back to live in the after life without all those things.

Comment: The questions above are really my own questions regarding life after death. Unfortunately, I haven't found any solid answers to that. Well, it's been a while since I've looked for answers. Perhaps it's time to continue this quest. In this comments, I simply want to point out that there's a good chance our state of emotions might be totally different in this life and in the after life. So I think it's better to understand that state of emotions first before trying to understand what will happen if our emotions stay the same.

Comment: Possibly being bored in jannah is a valid point. Living for eternity even if it is bliss is worrying. Perhaps it would be better if Allah wipes us out after a while in jannah.

Comment: Maybe there will be always something new to do in Jannah so no being bored, we have to understand that our Allah is all-powerful and most wise Lord He can remove negative emotions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that Jannah is designed in such a way that our desires are satisfied, so we can reasonably expect we will not experience boredom (at least, not in a negative way).

From the Qur'an:

> Look how We have favored [in provision] some of them over others. **But the Hereafter is greater in degrees [of difference] and greater in distinction.** -- [Qur'an 17:21](https://quran.com/17:21)
>
> He who has settled us in the home of duration out of His bounty. **There touches us not in it any fatigue, and there touches us not in it weariness [of mind].**" -- [Qur'an 35:35](https://quran.com/35:35)
>
> We were your allies in the worldly life and in the Hereafter. **And you will have therein whatever your souls desire, and you will have therein whatever you request** -- [Qur'an 41:31](https://quran.com/41:31)
>
> Circulated among them will be plates and vessels of gold. **And therein is whatever the souls desire and [what] delights the eyes**, and you will abide therein eternally. -- [Qur'an 43:71](https://quran.com/43:71)

And ahadith:

> The Messenger of Allah said, "...**You will have whatever your soul desires and whatever your eyes could delight in.** ..."' ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1883))
>
> The Messenger of Allah said, "The lowest place of any of you in Jannah will be that Allah will tell him to express his wish. He will wish and wish again. Allah will then ask him: 'Have you expressed your wish?' He will answer: 'Yes, I have.' Allah will say: '**You will have what you have wished for and the like thereof along with it.**"' -- Abu Hurairah ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1893))

How precisely Allah has designed it is not fully clear, as in the hadith:

> ... No person knows what is kept hidden for them of joy as a reward for what they used to do. ... -- Mu'adh bin Jabal ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1522))

But we know it involves [gardens beneath which rivers flow](https://quran.com/3:15), [women becoming virgins again](https://quran.com/56:36), [rivers of purified honey](https://quran.com/47:15), etc., from the Qur'an.

Here are some online fatawa that generally agree that in Jannah there is no boredom:

> Here no difficulty will ever afflict us, nor shall any tiredness touch us. From [Qur'an 35:35], **we gather that the boredom is a sign of difficulty and tiredness and obviously in paradise there is no such thing.**  -- Mufti Ebrahim Desai (sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/15801))
>
> Once you understand this, you will know that the man in Paradise will have the enjoyment of his wives from this world and al-hoor al-‘iyn, in a manner that will suffice him and give him everlasting and unceasing pleasure, and will also give his wives joy and pleasure, without anything to spoil it, and **with no end to the pleasure and no tiredness or boredom.** -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/173281)
>
> Paradise, or Jannah in Arabic, is the abode that Allah has prepared for believers. It holds means of everlasting bliss no eye has seen, no ear has heard and no human has imagined. In it are pure female mates, rivers of milk, rivers of wine, rivers of pure honey and every kind of delicious fruit and meat. **Its residents will not experience exhaustion, boredom or death.** -- [IslamWeb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/womane/nindex.php?page=readart&id=134429)

Answer (score -1):

U got this all wrong.Allah created us in a way that we are never satisfied,but in heaven Allah can change our desire and make us satisfied.the experience in heaven will never become boring

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn how this site works, and please cite sources and thoroughly answer the question asked.